# Advice on mysql table design

Tags: mysql, join

Currently I am updating database design and I am at point where I need some guidance.

Current Structure:

**Table called "person_skill" has following columns:**

```
id
person_id
Skill Name
```

And We are going to query table for:

Show me all people with one or more skills since person can have one or more skills.

Query:

```
select a.person_id, a.skillname, b.skillname, c.skillname
from person_skill a, person_skill b, person_skill c
where a.skillname='Java'
and b.skillname='SQL'
and c.skillname='Javascript'
and a.person_id = b.person_id
and a.person_id = c.person_id;
```

Currently there are around 50k records ( and expecting table to grows in millions of rows in production) in table and many of the skillname is duplicate. Unique skill names around 8k.

Above query return results but I am afraid that once we have millions of rows that will drastically reduce performance or worse it will crash.

Any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to normalize your tables, recommended read [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization).

**Person_Table**
ID,
FName,
LName,
SSN,
...

**Skill_Table**
ID,
Skill

**PersonXSkill_Table**
Person_ID,
Skill_ID

Comment: Thanks I have already separated first two tables, however, I am wondering should in keep personXskill table as person_id,skill_id or person_id, allskills(comma separated skill_id).

Comment: You do not want to have multiple skills listed in a single row, this makes querying the data difficult and is just plain bad practice.

Comment: Ok, in case of that when I would be searching for person with multiple skills, I have to do self join on millions of rows and wouldn't that be expensive for table with size of millions of rows? And number of tables involves directly related to number of skills in search.

Comment: You can cut this down to two tables which will improve performance slightly; however when you are talking millions of rows this should not be a problem at all and the above design allows for the most flexibility and manageability... If we were talking billions of rows then I would recommend a different approach, perhaps an OLAP approach rather than OLTP.